# How to use the Node’s fetch() in the same way as Request? (API rejects KEY)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-fetch

In my application, I use the `async/await` logic for working with an [API](https://gate.io/api2).

The problem is I can’t figure out why the `check()` function works with no hassle:

```
const KEY    = 'my key';
const SECRET = 'my secret';

function getSign(form) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha512', SECRET).update(form).digest('hex').toString();
}

async function check() {
  let form    = {};
  let header  = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
  header.KEY  = KEY;
  header.SIGN = await getSign(querystring.stringify(form));

  // Checking the state (works)!
  let info = await fetch(API_TRADE_URL + OPENORDERS_URL, { method:'POST', headers:header, form:form })
      info = info.json();

  return info;
}
```

… while the `placeOrder()` function fails and the API sends a message there is a problem with KEY/SECRET (`Invalid data`):

```
async function placeOrder ( currencyPair, rate, amount ) {
  let form     = { 'currencyPair':currencyPair, 'rate':rate, 'amount':amount };
  let header   = {};
  header.KEY   = KEY;
  header.SIGN  = getSign(querystring.stringify(form));

  // Here I am placing the order (does not work!)
  let orderRes = await fetch(API_TRADE_URL + BUY_URL, { method:'POST', headers:header, form:form } );
      orderRes = orderRes.json();
  return orderRes;
}
```

I was suspicious about the KEY/SECRET pair or the `getSign()` function but the `buy()` function (based on Node’s `request`) provided as a demo on the API’s site (the function which I am trying to mimic) works as expected:

```
function buy(currencyPair, rate, amount, cp) {
   let form = {'currencyPair':currencyPair,'rate':rate,'amount':amount};
   let header = {};
   header.KEY = KEY;
   header.SIGN = getSign(querystring.stringify(form));

   // Here I am placing the order (works!)
   Request({method: 'POST', url: API_TRADE_URL + BUY_URL, headers: header, form:form }, function (res) { console.log(res) });
 }
```

The important thing here is I don’t want to use the `buy()` function because I need to work without callbacks here. I use the same data, the same logic (working in the `check()` function mentioned above) but it fails in the case of the `placeOrder` function.

Comment: it would help to know what third party your trying to access so we can read it's documentation.

Comment: What status code are you getting on placeOrder?, 400 or 401/403?. It's hard for us to help you if we can't reproduce the error, since we don't know what API you're using.

Comment: Thank you! [Here](https://gate.io/api2) is the API docs. [Here](https://gate.io/api2) is the demo. As for the status code, the API responds with 200, but it rejects my logging information as `Invalid data`.

Comment: what logging information? Show where you're getting 'Invalid data'. If the API response with 200, I doubt the fetch isn't working.

Comment: Oh, I guess I’d better say credentials or so. Key/secret encoded by the `getSign` function. It seems the API rejects this peice of information. In the case of the `check` function it accepts them. I send the request, the API responds succesfully but does not accept the credentials (the cipher) but it should as it does if I use the Request method.